# Building HHVM missing GCC 4.7 but it is installed

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, hhvm

I try to compile HHVM on Ubuntu 12.04 according to [this manual](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-Ubuntu-12.04).

I am getting this error:

```
$ cmake .
Using HPHP_HOME == /home/foo/dev/hhvm
-- CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH was missing, proceeding anyway
CMake Error at CMake/HPHPCompiler.cmake:11 (message):
  Need at least GCC 4.7
```

But GCC 4.7 seems to be installed properly

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-2ubuntu1~12.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-2ubuntu1~12.04)
```

Comment: Could cmake be pointing to a specific compiler by path, that is different to whichever one you have globally available?

Comment: How did you install gcc 4.7? 12.04 ships with 4.6. You might need to set gcc 4.7 as default, have you done that?

Comment: I installed it from a PPA like in the linked guide and did update-alternatives